# Google Cloud SQL instance fills up to 10 TB

Tags: google-cloud-sql

An instance of our Google Cloud SQL instance filled up to 10 TB of disk space (thank you auto expansion ;) with a lot of

```
[Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4546ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=9360 and evicted=13008, during the time.)
```

log entries.
We restarted it and now disk space is back to ~250GB. However the instance still seems to have 10TB of SSD attached and I could not find a way to reduce it back to 500 GB in the ui (seems only storage increase is supported). Any pointers to reduce disk usage?

Comment: Did you ever get help with this? Seems like a major problem and we just started seeing it.

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply. yes, google support got back to us. the resolution was to  migrate to a new db instances as you could not shrink the disk.